# Javascript: Trying to use var in switch: "var is declared but its value is never read"

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I declared `var x` and `var y` in a function:

```
var x = document.getElementById("x").value;
var y = document.getElementById("y").value;
```

I did this because I need to use `document.getElementById` several times.

Also in this function I have a switch-case.
In all cases I need to use `var x` and `var y`.

I get the warning that `var x` and `var y` is never read.

I used a if-Statement before but I think that using a switch-case is better in this situation.

When I use `document.getElementById("x").value` instead of `var x` it works but I don't want to call `document.getElementById` in 10 cases.

```
function showOptions(s) {

    var x = document.getElementById("x").value; //"never used"
    var y = document.getElementById("y").value; //"never used"

        switch (s[s.selectedIndex].id) {

            case "case1":
                document.getElementById("x").value = "1"; //works
                document.getElementById("y").value = "2"; //works
                break;

            case "case2":
                x = "2"; //does not work
                y = "4"; //does not work
                break;
    }
```

Comment: You have to actually *do* something with your selected elements, else the linter will warn you that you declared a variable but never used it.

Comment: Also, `x` and `y` dont exist in *this* function :) Suggested read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Comment: Actually in your case2, x and y are not initialised anywhere. Your variable names are cpu and ram. Not x and y as you are saying

Comment: change the name `x` will be `cpu` and `y` will `ram`

Comment: If you want concise code, consider using an object indexed by cases instead of `switch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> var cpu = document.getElementById("x").value; //"never used"
> ```

The `value` property of an element is a string. When you copy the value of that property to a variable, you copy the string.

> ```
> cpu = "2"; //does not work
> ```

If you copy a new value to the variable, then you change the value of **the variable**.

It is **not** a reference to the `value` property of an object. It has no connection to the element.

If the value you copied was a reference to an object:

```
var cpu = document.getElementById("x");
```

… then you could access the object and update the property:

```
cpu.value = "2";
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me out!

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the object reference, instead of a variable with a primitive value.

```
function showOptions(s) {
    var cpu = document.getElementById("x"); // take object
    var ram = document.getElementById("y");

    switch (s[s.selectedIndex].id) {
        case "case1":
            cpu.value = "1"; // use property of object
            ram.value = "2";
            break;
        case "case2":
            cpu.value = "2";
            ram.value = "4";
            break;
    }
}
```